# Highcharts dynamic-master-detail chart incorrectly identifies date range at selection

Tags: highcharts

I have a dynamic-master-details Highcharts chart where the master chart has an area and multiple column - type chart series. The issue is that when selecting a date period from the master chart (the smaller chart at the bottom) the actual selection on the master chart shows the originally selected date period incorrectly - not as it was just selected b ythe mouse (usually shows a shorter date period by a few days, but sometimes shows longer ones).

I have created an example from the stock dynamic-master-details chart example from Highcharts by adding additional columns to display on the master chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/XpZWh/3/

```
            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                yAxis: 0,
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 01),
                data: data
            },
            {
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 01),
                data: data2
            },
            {
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 01),
                data: data3
            }],
```

Any idea why is this behavior? Any chance this is a Highcharts bug?

Comment: Should we check any specific date? I have tried to zoom May 07 -> Sep 07. It showed in alert May 01 3:30 -> Sep 29 5.20, and chart displayed points from May 02 to Sep 29 which is correctly. Remember, when you are using timestamps in data points, remove pointStart and pointInterval from that series.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to remove pointStart and pointInterval and make the whole interval smaller so it is easier to reproduce - but strangely I cannot reproduce it anymore... Apologies.